# JQuery SyntaxError: unterminated string literal because of break line in textarea

Tags: jquery, string, syntax-error

i have a textarea in my jquery code, when user types some string that contains break lines in textarea, it will save in the table correctly. but when i try to show this string in edit page it causes this jquery error because of the enters:

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

this is my code:

```
+ '<textarea  placeholder="content"  class="form-control " rows="5"  type="text" name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][text]" style="display: inline;"  required ><?php echo @$text; ?></textarea>'
```

i had to preg_replace the break lines temporarily to prevent error:

$text = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", " ", $text );

but i need the breake lines in my string, is there any way to prevent this error or any solution to handle this problem? i appreciate any help ..

here is what happens in my jquery when i trying to echo $text variable that contains the string with enter:

```
+ '<textarea  placeholder="content"  class="form-control " rows="5"  type="text" name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][text]" style="display: inline;"  required >this is a text with break line
this is the rest of text after break line
```

'

and the all code:

```
        <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          console.log('hwllo');

            var index = 0;
            console.log(index);

            var addmorehtml = '';


            <?php foreach ($interactive_contents as $interactive_content) {  ?>



      <?php $id = @$interactive_content['InteractiveContent']['id']; 
            $code = @$interactive_content['InteractiveContent']['code']; 
            $text = @$interactive_content['InteractiveContent']['text']; 
            // $text = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", " ", $text );
            ?>

       addmorehtml  +=  '<div index="'+index+'" id="interactive_content'+ index +'"   style="display :inline;">'


                    + '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control " value = "<?php echo @$id; ?>" type="hidden" name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][id]" style="display: inline; width: 200px;" required /></div>'

                    + '<div class="form-group"><span class="red">*</span><input class="form-control " onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 0 && event.charCode <= 57" placeholder="کد محتوای تعاملی"  value = "<?php echo @$code; ?>" type="text" name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][code]" style="display: inline; width: 200px;" /></div>'

                    + '<div class="form-group"><span class="red">*</span><textarea  placeholder="متن محتوای تعاملی"  class="form-control " rows="5"  type="text" name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][text]" style="display: inline;"  required >\'<?php echo @$text; ?>\'</textarea><a  onclick="$('+"interactive_content"+index+').remove(); " id="del_items_2'+ index +'" href="#"">حذف</a></div></br></div>' 

                index++;


            <?php } ?>


            $("#interactive_content").html(addmorehtml);

        });
</script>


 <a id="addmore" href="#addmore"><span style   ="font-size: 15px"><b>+ افزودن محتوای تعاملی </b></span> </a>
```

Comment: We need to see the code that causes the problem. There shouldn't be any problem sending data to and from server that has line breaks in it

Comment: That's not a full variable....that's a snippet in the middle of some concatenation.

Comment: use a code linter...will show you exactly where problems are

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `'` inside `'`s.

```
+ '<textarea  
    placeholder="content"
    class="form-control"
    rows="5"
    type="text" 
    name="InteractiveContent[' + index + '][text]" // error is here
    style="display: inline;"
    required 
  >
    this is a text with break line
    this is the rest of text after break line
  </textarea>'
```

You need to use `\'` so the parser does not think your string ends there:

```
+ '<textarea  
    placeholder="content"
    class="form-control"
    rows="5"
    type="text" 
    name="InteractiveContent[\' + index + \'][text]"
    style="display: inline;"
    required 
  >
    this is a text with break line
    this is the rest of text after break line
  </textarea>'
```

Comment: thanks but my problem is with this part:
   +'<textarea> <?php echo @$text; ?></textarea>'
the variable $text contains enter. i tried  +'<textarea>\' <?php echo @$text; ?>\'</textarea>' but it dosnt help.

Answer (score 0):

see this plunker may be it's helpful for you

```
var str = new String(document.querySelector(".form-control").value);
var newstr = str.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/78CCoOsFWo8iEuE7DRz3?p=preview

Comment: it replaces <br> instead of enters and the srting would be like 'this is a text </br> with break line' but i dont want the '<br>' to be in my string i want to send this content to my users and they see some br tags in the text...

Comment: it's depend to you. if send this content to users by web then **<br/>** auto convert into **new line** but if any other way you send data to your users then not replace with **<br/>**